# Xamarin.Forms iOS Simulator Build for Facebook Review

Tags: ios, facebook, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How can i generate a Simulator Build with Xamarin? I'm using Xamarin.Forms and Facebook SDK component.

This is needed in order to upload the app for Facebook review:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/creating-ios-simulator-build-for-review#generate-simulator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may actually build the project with **Release** + **iPhone 4s iOS** (to make an `i386` build) configuration.

Then you should be able to find *YourProject.app* under `YOUR_IOS_PROJECT_PATH/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Release`. After that just follow remaining steps in the [facebook guideline](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/advanced#sim_build) starting from *Compress the Simulator Build Into a .zip File*.

Comment: Addition: if you're using the Unified API, make sure you're not building a fat app (in your project's iOS Build options (Advanced page), make sure the architecture is either i386 or x86_64, but not both, since Xamarin.iOS does not build shippable fat apps, they're a special format which is modified to be a real app when launched by the IDE).

Comment: @Alex Lau, it appears the renaming steps in that link no longer exist.

Comment: @BradMoore, they have moved the page to "Advanced Topics" and I have updated the answer. Thanks for that!